# Foreign Key is not added to destination table after the creation of a relationship class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class

Let's say I have two tables A and B. The relationship between these two tables is as follows :

A (1,*) <---- (1,1) B

Now when I try to add a relationship class for these two tables on Arcatalog, I right-click on the .sde file in Arcatalog and then :

New ==> relationship class.

For the origin table I choose A, and for the destination table I choose B

(Is that right btw or should it be the opposite?)

For the type of the relation ship I select : Simple (Peer to Peer) relationship

Direction : Both

The cardinality of the relationship class : (1 - m) One to Many

And after that I get to select the primary key field in the origin table and the foreign key in the destination table:

[image: Keys]

As you can see for the foreign key it actually gives me the objectid of that table, now I need to understand if I have to **manually** add the foreign key field in that table and then select it here?

Shouldn't it be created automatically after the relationship class is created? Obviously when I click on Next and I go back to my postgresql table no foreign key is added.. and it's confusing 'cause I thought that once we define a relationship automatically the id of the origin table migrates to the destination table and becomes a foreign key!

I had to use this database in a web application using ASP.NET, with Entity Framework, and I got confused after Entity Framework has generated the model from my database (at first I added the FK manually).. So now I'm doing it all over again and I would like to do it the right way..

How can I define the foreign keys and the relationship classes from arcatalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vince:

> Relationship classes tell the geodatabase about existing
>   relationships. The key columns need to exist. There are many reasons
>   why the columns should be created with the table, most importantly, to
>   avoid the fragmentation caused by adding a column.
>
> If you don't define the relationships in the geodatabase (not all of
>   which support the concept of foreign keys, so they are optional), then
>   you don't get the [benefits of relationship
>   classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004t00000003000000).

@BenSNadler:

> The foreign key options in the dialog filter based on the input field
>   data type. If the foreign key field does not exist you need to
>   manually add it. I suggest using the arcgis tool [add field
>   management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B7000000)
>   to be clear. The geodatabase relationship does not place any database
>   level constraints on the field. To the DB it is just a regular field.

I added those fields manually and then created the relationship classes.